# Error en maquetacion de footer

Tags: html, css

tengo el error de que cuando le doy estilo al footer, que es solamente las palabras "derechos reservados", me le da estilo a toda el main de la pagina, en este caso puse un background gris:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca estan los codigos del html y css:

html:

```
<footer>
    <p>Todos los derechos reservados ©.</p>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer p{
    background-color: #aaa ;
}
```

Comment: Estaria genial que nos compartieras la estructura HTML de tu proyecto, para ver si en algun lado hayas dejado una etiqueta sin cerrar, lo que dejas como ejemplo no se puede testear.

Comment: Podrias incluir todo el codigo para que lo podamos entender mejor?